# Fonts and spacing seem to have changed after installation of a package

Tags: fonts

To get WindowBuilder in Eclipse to work I had to install some dependencies. One of them seems to have changed the font everywhere, even in the terminals. It somehow looks like KDE fonts.

These are the ones that I installed:

- libiw-dev
- libhunspell-1.3-0
- libasound2-dev
- libnotify-dev
- libdbus-glib-1-dev
- libgtk2.0-dev
- libgtk2.0-0
- gtk2-engines
- libidl-dev
- libhunspell-dev
- libstdc++6-4.4-dev
- pango-graphite

Which one could be the one that changed it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's pango-graphite. Pango is a library for layout and rendering of text, with an emphasis
on internationalization. From the pango-graphite package description:

> SILGraphite is a system that can be used to create and use "smart
>   fonts" capable of displaying writing systems with various complex
>   behaviors, such as: contextual shaping, ligatures, reordering, split
>   glyphs, bidirectionality, stacking diacritics and complex positioning.

For more details see this bug report: [Pango-graphite changes default UI font in Ubuntu 13.04](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pango-graphite/+bug/1176022).